# Why is the parskip package messing up the spacing in mdframed?

Tags: spacing, mdframed

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
  innerlinewidth=0.5pt,
  middlelinewidth=1.5pt,
  middlelinecolor=white,
  innertopmargin=0]{theo}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Everything looks great: there's a nice inner margin for the theorem and the spacing above and beneath are beautifully equal.

Now, I'd like to use the parskip package, but when I enable it, I get this ugly result:

[image: Messed up spacing.]

I could try to tweak all these margins seperately and see what looks best (I'd for example use `innertopmargin=12pt`), but that doesn't seem like a great solution in the long term.

How can I get the previous correct spacing back?

Comment: replace `innertopmargin=0` with `innertopmargin=\topskip`

Comment: @touhami: The theorem being displayed partly outside of the box is only one part of the problem. There's also the space between the text and the box that isn't the same above and below anymore. I can try to tweak all these margins seperately and see what looks best (I'd for example use `innertopmargin=12pt`), but that doesn't seem like a great solution in the long term to me.

Comment: see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdframed/mdframed.pdf#page=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mdfsetup` instead of `surroundwithmdframed` did the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\mdfsetup{
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    innerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    middlelinewidth=1.5pt,
    middlelinecolor=white,
    innertopmargin=\topskip,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=0,
    nobreak=true
}

\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: Nice spacing.]